# Communication Between Multiple devices.

Tags: java, android, web-services

I am designing a simple Android application (might be ported to iOS in the future) where I want to have real-time communication between multiple devices. The procedure is that one device(creator) makes a "lobby" that have certain ID, using this ID other devices should be able to join this "lobby" and wait for messages from the creator. Then clients connected to the "lobby" should be able to respond to the messages from the creator. The connection should only be active for couple of minutes and no need to store the messages on the server side.

I am not sure what methods I should look into to archive this functionality. I have looked at comet, but I am not sure if that is the way to go for this project.

Have anyone solved similar problem? And if so how did you do it and what libraries/frameworks did you use?

Comment: Should devices connect to each other through internet?

Comment: Preferably through the internet, at least not through bluetooth.
Could I implement this like a multi-player game? Are there any good tutorials on how client-server or peer-2-peer is implemented in android multi-player games?